# Express.js with EJS application bug: the edit form does not indicate the current category of the post

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am working on a **[blogging application](https://github.com/Ajax30/XPressBlog)** (click the link to see the **GitHub** repo) with [Express](https://expressjs.com/), [EJS](https://ejs.co/) and MongoDB.

I have *Posts* and *Post Categories*, each in its own collection.

In the *Edit posts* form (as well as in the *Add New Post* form) there is a select-box with the available categories:

```
<% if (categories) { %>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="categores">Choose a post category</label>
        <select id="categores" name="category" class="form-control">
            <% categories.forEach(function(category, index) { %>
                <option value="<%= category._id %>" selected="<%= category._id == post.category._id ? 'selected' : ''; %>"><%= category.cat_name %></option>
            <% }); %>
        </select>
   </div>
<% } %>
```

The problem is that the select-box above does not have the category that the post is *currently into*, selected. I have not be able to find out why.

This does not work either:

```
<option value="<%= category._id %>" <%= category._id == post.category._id ? 'selected' : ''; %>><%= category.cat_name %></option>
```

In the posts controller I have:

```
exports.editPost = (req, res, next) => {
    const postId = req.params.id;

    Post.findById(postId, function(err, post) {
        const categories = Category.find({}, (err, categories) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Error: ', err);
            } else {
                res.render('admin/editpost', {
                    layout: 'admin/layout',
                    website_name: 'MEAN Blog',
                    page_heading: 'Dashboard',
                    page_subheading: 'Edit Post',
                    categories: categories,
                    post: post
                });
            }
        });
    });
}

exports.updatePost = (req, res, next) => {

    const query = {
        _id: req.params.id
    }

    const form = {
        titleholder: req.body.title,
        excerptholder: req.body.excerpt,
        bodyholder: req.body.body
    };

    const errors = validationResult(req);

    const post = {};

    post._id = req.params.id;
    post.title = req.body.title;
    post.short_description = req.body.excerpt
    post.full_text = req.body.body;
    post.category = req.body.category;
    if (req.file) {
        post.post_image = req.file.filename;
    }

    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        req.flash('danger', errors.array())
        res.render('admin/editpost', {
            layout: 'admin/layout',
            website_name: 'MEAN Blog',
            page_heading: 'Dashboard',
            page_subheading: 'Edit Post',
            form: form,
            post: post
        });
    } else {
        Post.update(query, post, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return;
            } else {
                req.flash('success', "The post was successfully updated");
                req.session.save(() => res.redirect('/dashboard'));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making sure you are comparing 2 strings:

```
<option value="<%= category._id %>" <%= category._id.toString() == post.category._id.toString() ? 'selected' : ''; %>><%= category.cat_name %></option>
```